# Keyboard assistance for iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

My game has a swipe up gesture recognition that does something. Because I use it a lot and making swipe on iPhone Simulator is not easy I want to use the real keyboard instead.
How can I capture the real keyboard (the one connected to the pc running the simulator) presses to do the thing instead of having to swipe with the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would suggest using real hardware to do this if thats the problem. But you obviously dont want to take that route OR, dont want to pay the $99 bucks yet. So I suggest creating a macro that does the mouse movement for you.  You can create a macro that repeatedly does a mouse click, move and unclick (a swipe gesture). Over and over again with a pause interval inbetween. You can then set a hotkey like (CTRL + M) that will start and stop the macro.  Good luck.

Comment: I would google "Macro for iMac" and find a free/free trial software. Download it and in the macro editor there will probably be some kind of "record" option that will record you mouse movements. Click record, so you can record your movements and the macro will learn what it is that you are doing. Save the macro, and run it when you want to test your swipe gesture. Its not "easy as pie" it will take a little bit of research and testing to get the macro correct. But thats probably your best option.

Comment: Isn't there any other way? safari on the simulator can accept real keyboard input